# Display checkbox options based on dropdown value in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

once i select a particular value in dropdown menu based on that corresponding checkbox values should display

this is for getting dropdown values dynamically, based on this below i should get checkbox values

```
<tr>
        <?php
        $sub=mysql_query("select * from subjects");
        $suboption='';
        while($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($sub))
        {
            $suboption .='<option value = '.$row['sub_id'].'>'.$row['subname'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
      <td width="15%">Subject :</td>
      <td id="add_subject"><div id="add_subject1">
          <select name="subject" id="subject" onchange="subjectskills(this.value)">
              <option value="">Select Subject</option>
              <?php echo $suboption; ?>
          </select>
          </div></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Use *AJAX* for dynamic loading. *jQuery AJAX* is especially easy to use in my personal opinion...

Answer (score 0):

You should create a 'div' tag where the updated checkbox values would be displayed through ajax. This is the following function which is called everytime the listbox value changes:
This is the script function:

```
function subjectskills(value)
{
    var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("check_box").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","subjectskills?from="+value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is the div tag for checkbox:

```
    <div id="check_box"></div>
```

Here's subjectskills.php:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['from']))
    {
        $from=$_GET['from'];
        echo"<input type='checkbox' value='$from'>$from";
    }
?>
```